# Extension whitelist doesn't seem to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have a problem with carrierwave gem. Extension_whitelist doesn't seem to work.

```
  def extension_whitelist
    %w(csv)
  end
```

I have no clue why it does not work. It doesn't matter what type of file I import, it never raises an error.
Here is rest of my code:

```
class AttachmentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_whitelist
    %w(csv)
  end

end
```

And controller (basically clear scaffold with formatting and responds)

```
class PackagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_package, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /packages
  # GET /packages.json
  def index
    @packages = Package.all
  end

  # GET /packages/1
  # GET /packages/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /packages/new
  def new
    @package = Package.new
  end

  # GET /packages/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /packages
  # POST /packages.json
  def create
    @package = Package.new(package_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @package.save
        format.html { redirect_to @package, notice: 'Package was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @package }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @package.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /packages/1
  # PATCH/PUT /packages/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @package.update(package_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @package, notice: 'Package was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @package }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @package.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /packages/1
  # DELETE /packages/1.json
  def destroy
    @package.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to packages_url, notice: 'Package was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_package
      @package = Package.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def package_params
      params.require(:package).permit(:name, :description, :category_id)
    end
end
```

Searching for answers I have also seen:

```
  def content_type_whitelist
    /csv\//
  end
```

but it doesn't work too.
Any ideas what could be the problem?
Also, is there any other simple way to implement that?

@EDIT Problem has been solved: I reported this bug quite long time ago and it has been recently fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The method needs to be called `extension_white_list` and not `extension_whitelist`.

On the master branch This has recently been renamed to `extension_whitelist` (see [commit](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/commit/06003a5044190f93d07d958b6ca9fd6f6f8fbdb2)) but this change has not made into a publicly released gem yet.

Comment: Tried both, listed extension_whitelist because it was in official notes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this in model

```
validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, :content_type => 'text/plain'
```

also find out what you want to whitelist here is the complete list of filetypes http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/

Comment: The problem is "text/plain" type is not as specific as I want it to be. I need it to be "x seperated value" where x would be punctuation mark chosen from list. Although, If I check first line of given document (no headers) for specific number of words (which should always be the same) seperated by given punctuation mark it could work. But there is a problem, I would have to download this file from user first and that's what I try to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your comments, the File_validators gem is what you are looking for:
https://github.com/musaffa/file_validators

You will be able to validate files before upload (size and content type).